# Python 3.6 Create mapping from an array with sizes

Tags: python, python-3.x, mapping, python-3.6

**Task**

I have an array with sizes

```
sizes = [5, 3, 1, 2]
```

and based on the sizes I want to create the following array

```
mapping = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
```

**Solution**

My first attempt

```
mapping = []
ctr = 0
for i in range(len(sizes)):
    for j in range(sizes[i]):
        mapping.append(i)
        ctr += 1
```

Shorter version

```
mapping = [[i for _ in range(sizes[i])] for i in range(len(sizes))]
mapping = list(itertools.chain(*mapping))
```

**Question**

One line version?

Is it possible to do it in just one line with a neat code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
sizes = [5, 3, 1, 2]
result = [i for i, v in enumerate(sizes) for _ in range(v)]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to multiply the indices into sublists `[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2], [3, 3]]`
 then flatten the result with [`itertoo.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> sizes = [5, 3, 1, 2]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable([i] * x for i, x in enumerate(sizes)))
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
```